# Angular2 Using a service to maintain state

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a service that holds the state of the current route. I can't figure out how to do that as I thought my current implementation would work:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    PagesModule,
    UIModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [HelpersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

helpers.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class HelpersService {
  activePage = '';
  constructor() {}

  setActivePage(name) {
    this.activePage = name;
  }

  getActivePage() {
    return this.activePage;
  }

}
```

dashboard.component.ts (part of PagesModule)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private _helpersService: HelpersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._activeRoute.data.subscribe(
      value => {
        this._helpersService.setActivePage(value); 
      }
    );

  }

}
```

top-bar.component.ts(part of UIModule)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.scss']
})
export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {
  // holds the active page
  activePage:string;

  constructor(private _helpersService: HelpersService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activePage = this._helpersService.getActivePage();
  }

}
```

This is always returning undefined.

Comment: This seems to depend on `setActivePage()` being called before `getActivePage()` How can you be sure that's happening?

Comment: That's probably what's happening. How would you suggest approaching this?

Comment: Rather than create a service to pass a value from an existing service, I would just subscribe to `activeRoute` in both components.

Comment: Yeap, that's what I went for in the end. Thanks so much for your help!